# regex for matching a string with a number in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as below.

```
"Included in PTA fees" or "Included in PTA fees 33$" or "Included in PTA fees $60"
```

I need to match this string with searching for PTA fee/fees and whether any fee(number) is also appended with it.

**Need to look for "PTA fees" along with fee value in any given string and return true.**

So it should return true for

```
"Included in PTA fees 33$" and
"Included in PTA fees $60"
```

It should return false for `"Included in PTA fees"`

I tried with below regular expression. but it returns true for

```
"Included in PTA fees"

/#{PTA_FEE[0-9]}/i.match?(value)
```

Comment: like [`this`](http://www.rubular.com/r/yWg2OrS3cN)

Comment: @rock321987 It wont match with "Misc charges are  Included in PTA fees 33$"?? So I think we can omit ^.*

Comment: it will match.. you can check [`here`](http://www.rubular.com/r/NYNPAHEAtI)

Comment: @rubyist: Your counter-example "Misc charges are ..." was not part of your original description.

Comment: @rock321987 /^.*#{PTA_FEE}(?=.*\d+)/.match?(value) did not match "Included in PTA fee 12$"

value is "Included in PTA fee 12$"

Comment: @rubyist you are using wrong syntax.. `{}` have special meaning in regex

Comment: @rock321987I think i have not explained you clearly. I want to match the string with PTA fees/fee accompanied with any number and $
.i.e. Match any string and return true if it has PTA fee/fees with fee value.

Comment: @rubyist updated

Comment: What `#{PTA_FEE[0-9]}` refers to?

Comment: #{PTA_FEE} PTA_FEE is a referring to a constant value.

Comment: To date, four answers have been posted. You have not awarded the green checkmark to any of them, so we infer that you didn't find any helpful. Yet you provided zero feedback, so how are the authors of those answers to know how they could modify their answers to meet your needs? Considerable amounts of time were put into those answers. Have you no appreciation for those efforts?

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work

```
^.*PTA fees?(?=.*(?:(?:\d+\s*\$)|(?:\$\s*\d+)))
```

Regex Breakdown

```
(?i) #Ignore Case
^ #Start of string
.*
PTA fees? #Match the string with fee(s)
(?=.* #Lookahead

  (?: #Non capturing group

     (?:\d+\s*\$) #Match digit followed by $

        | #Alternation

     (?:\$\s*\d+) #Match $ followed digit

  ) #End non capturing group
) #End lookahead
```

[**`rubular demo`**](http://www.rubular.com/r/7IilFr9TF1)

Answer (score 2):

You simply need `\S+` as end part of your regex:

```
str =~ /Included in PTA fees? \S+/
```

- `\S+` One or more non-whitespace character(s)
- `?` Optional match

or to be more precise:

```
str =~ /Included in PTA fees? (?:\d+\$|\$\d+)/
```

[Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/UcvEVl1u8Q)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [`Included in PTA fees(?=.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))`](https://regex101.com/r/7hvKkG/1); this also groups the fee and takes into account floating-point values. But it doesn't take into account any free-form negation such as "*aren't* included in PTA fees" or "*not* included in PTA fees".

It disregards the dollar sign; since your description is incomplete and what you're matching against looks like something that is potentially grammatically incorrect, you may have `\$\s*\d+|\d+\s*\$` for the dollar sign. Does the dollar value potentially have a thousand separator?

You can complicate the answer to this question quite a lot when the problem is under-specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
^Included in PTA fees\s*(\$\d+|\d+\$)
```

It checks if string starts with `Included in PTA fees` and then allows fee number with a dollar sign before (`\$\d+`) or after it (`\d+\$`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kgocfq/1/)